# C++ Inheritance operator=

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdvector

I know this question has been asked previously; however, I'm not understanding the solutions. I'm trying to create a subclass to std::vector, it's able to inherate member functions (such as `push_back`), but not operators (such as `=`).
From [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894090/derived-class-inherit-base-class-assignment-operator) it seems like it should just happen automatically... is the vector class different?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class FortranArray1 : public std::vector<T> {
        public:
        T & operator()(int row)
        {
                return (*this)[row-1];
        }

};

int main()
{
        vector <double> y;
        y = {3};        // works
        vector <double> z = y; //works

        FortranArray1<double> x;
        x = {3};        // doesn't work
        x.push_back(3); // works
        cout << y[0] << x[0] << ", " << x(1) ;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate and the answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161569/4784683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `using` to introduce base class's `operator=`

```
template <class T>
class FortranArray1 : public std::vector<T> {
   public:
   using std::vector<T>::operator=;
   T & operator()(int row){return (*this)[row-1];}
};
```

you probably also need `using std::vector<T>::vector;` to introduce it's constructors

Comment: Why isn’t it inherited?

Comment: @Adrian because it is not supposed to? you class has it's own `operator=`, which has signature `operator=(const FortranArray1& another)` and would (effectively) call base class's `operator=`. but it does not mean your class would have a  `operator=(const base& another)`